# Git push to upstream fails with different remote branch name

Tags: git, version-control, git-remote

I have created a local branch

```
(master)$git checkout -b om-dev
(om-dev)$git branch -u origin/dev
```

[image: Show the tracking connection of local 'om-dev' to remote 'dev' from origin[1]]
Fig1: Show the tracking connection of local 'om-dev' to remote 'dev' from origin

```
(om-dev)$git branch -vv
```

[image: Confirm that my local branch is tracking remote correctly]

Fig2: Confirm that my local branch is tracking remote correctly

I have some local commits on 'om-dev' that I want to push to 'dev'

```
(om-dev)$git status
```

[image: Show local branch is ahead of remote]

Fig3: Show local branch is ahead of remote

**Now, issue comes here:**

```
(om-dev)$git push
```

Here, I expect to push my commit from om-dev branch to remote 'dev' branch without using full syntax (*$git push origin dev* or, *$git push -u origin dev*)
But, I am seeing following complaint:

[image: Complain pushing local branch]

Fig4: Complain pushing local branch, even after successful upstream set already

**Question:** Why do I again need to track my branch using -u in my push statement? Shouldn't logically after already setting upstream, it should be able to resolve the remote branch and source when I only use 'git push' command.

**Note:** I have already tried using -u option, and it works as expected. But I am expecting why it doesn't work this way?
The git version being used is: **2.19.1**.windows.1

Comment: Did you change your `push.default` setting, or is it defaulting to `simple`? (It's pretty clear that it is set to `simple`.)

Comment: Use this before you push "git config push.default upstream"

Comment: Thanks @torek the issue was the hidden push.default, which defaults was simple (by default). Setting it to upstream resolves, as suggested